# Python code to generate all the 6 digit numeric code

Tags: python

Am trying to use a brute force attack to generate all the whole possible 6-digit numeric code with python
i want all the code possible with this code from number 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

how do i generate all the possible digits code for a six digit using python.

```
import string
import random

def brute_force(size=6, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

print(brute_force)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: No need for randomisation. It's just *range(1000000)*

Comment: please give me a practical example

Comment: `(str(n).zfill(6) for n in range(1000000))` will generate the strings that you seek. You can loop over that generator expression.

Comment: `for x in range(1000000): print(str(x).zfill(6))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your possible passwords are all strings from 000000 to 999999, you can use range(1000000) to get the numbers below 1m and then format those numbers with leading zeros like this:

```
f"{password:06d}"
# or 
str(password).zfill(6)
```

As a loop:

```
for password in range(100):
    print(f"{password:06d}")
```

as a generator:

```
(str(n).zfill(6) for n in range(1000000))
```

as a list:

```
pw_list = [f"{password:06d}" for password in range(1000000)]
```

Comment: <function brute_force at 0x0000018F6E25F040> i got the error

Comment: Do you want to try just one random value from the possible passwords? Or do you want to try them systematically?

Comment: i want to try just one random value from the possible passwords

Comment: do i have to write this code in a single file first

Comment: Try: `print(random.choice([str(i).zfill(6) for i in range(1000000)]))`